# Vue-router does not catch routes with a dot in the webpack template

Tags: express, webpack, vue-router

I bootstrapped my application from [webpack template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack) and added the route `/edit/:filename` to it.

The problem is, filenames containing a dot are handled by Express and not by my Vue application.

In other words, `/edit/123` is matched by the route but `/edit/123.json` or `/edit/123.txt` is not and I get a 404 from Express.

How can I match anything or at least `/edit/anyfilename.json` in my route?

Comment: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/using-dots-in-vue-route-urls-webpack/5860/2 may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had an [answer](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-router-does-not-catch-routes-with-a-dot/14717) from [Linus Borg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1339840/linus-borg) on Vue forum. Vue [webpack template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack) uses `connect-history-api-fallback` to redirect all HTTP requests to `index.html`. It skips HTTP requests with a dot in the path unless `disableDotRule` is set to `true`. The proper config is

```
app.use(require('connect-history-api-fallback')({
  disableDotRule: true,
  rewrites: [
    {from: /\/app.js/, to: '/app.js'}
  ]
}))
```

Notice that we have to add an extra rewrite to `/app.js` so that it is not redirected to `index.html`.