# Why Vue-Router doesn't work with "." symbol?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I've set params on Vue-Router:

```
path: '/page/:Id', component: Page
```

But when i open `page/com.page`

It gives me `Cannot GET page/com.page`

Comment: Related question here check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45280091/vue-router-does-not-catch-routes-with-a-dot-in-the-webpack-template

Answer (score 0):

It's a common in a web server that if you put . in a url path it will returning a file. In your case it will calling a com.page file which is not available.
Perhaps you want to use dash '-' instead of dot '.' ?