# VUE JS Router - allow dot in router param

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

**I face an issue with allowing my router param have values with `.` (dot).**

For example, I have the following route setup:

```
{
  path: '/name/:name/city/:city',
  name: 'home',
  component: Home
}
```

In some cases, the value of the city can be: `boston` - `/name/joe/city/boston`.

Some other cases can be: `new.york` - `/name/joe/city/new.york`

The `boston` page will load, while the `new.york` page will fail on `404 not found`.

Like the route refuses to deal with the `.` (dot).

**The issue occurs only when reloading the page, and not while navigating between pages of the website itself.**

---

On the client side, I tried upgrading the `vue-router` version to `3.5.3`.

The vuejs router is set with: `new VueRouter({mode: 'history', routes});`

On the server side, I tried using `connect-history-api-fallback` [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-history-api-fallback):

```
const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');
app.use(history());
```

and also with:

```
app.use(history({disableDotRule: true}));
```

**The issue does not reproduce locally**, therefore I suspect it is caused by the `.htaccess` config.

I could not find a clear solution online and would appreciate a direction to solve the issue and allow route params with dots.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue-router does not catch routes with a dot in the webpack template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45280091/vue-router-does-not-catch-routes-with-a-dot-in-the-webpack-template)

Comment: It seems like the right direction. I've tried the `disableDotRule: true`. Regarding the other rewrite rule suggested, I could not find a good reference for it.

Comment: I updated the post, it does not reproduce locally, might be related to the `.htaccess` config.

Comment: Also tried updating the `webpack.config.js`

with ```devServer: { historyApiFallback: {disableDotRule: true}  }```